# DRF many-to-one reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an API endpoint returning pets and their owners.

- Each owner has a name and **one or more** pets
- Each pet has a name and **one** owner

Example Django models:

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Pet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I've configured my API to return JSON data like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Scotch",
        "owner": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Ben"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Fluffy",
        "owner": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Fred"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Spot",
        "owner": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Fred"
        }
    }
]
```

Example DRF serializers:

```
class OwnerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Owner
        fields = ("id", "name")

class PetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = OwnerSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = ("id", "name", "owner")
```

While that's all fine and dandy, I'd actually like to have an endpoint that returns a list of owners and their pets. So I'd get this data instead:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Fred",
        "pets": [
            { "id": 1, "name": "Spot" },
            { "id": 3, "name": "Fluffy" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ben",
        "pets": [
            { "id": 2, "name": "Scotch" }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I achieve that output?

Comment: The solution to this is actually demonstrated in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), with the line: `>>> r.article_set.all()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add `pet_set` field to OwnerSerializer like this:

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = ("id", "name")

class OwnerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    pet_set = PetSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Owner
        fields = ("id", "name", "pet_set")
```

This will work bacause many-to-one relation default reverse lookup name is `<model>_set` or `pet_set` in your case. You can change it by using `related_name`:

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, related_name='pets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In this case you can use `pets` name inside serializer:

```
class OwnerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    pets = PetSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Now  in `OwnerListView` you can use this new serializer:

```
class OwnerListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Owner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OwnerSerializer
```

Answer (score 3):

Change/ add your **serializer.py** as following

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = ("id", "name")


class OwnerNewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pets = PetSerializer(many=True, source='pet_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Owner
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'pets')
```

and **views.py**

```
class OwnerAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Owner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OwnerNewSerialize
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I’d be great if you provided a description as well

Comment: Sorry for the late reply :( This is what we call 'Nested Serializer` and You can find the official DRF documentation here, http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships