# How to optimize access to reverse ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(
        ModelA,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="model_bs"
    )
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to make request that returns all `ModelA`-s, including its main `ModelB`.

Like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "model_b": {
            "is_main": true
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "model_b": null
    }
]
```

I can achieve this with `SerializerModelMethod`:

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA

    def get_model_b(self, obj):
        model_b = obj.model_bs.filter(is_main=True).first()
        return ModelBSerializer(model_b).data
```

But it entails an **"n+1"** problem with DB. It will make additional query on every ModelA. And `prefetch_related` on `model_bs` won't help. How to optimize it?

Comment: try this it should work [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413143/drf-many-to-one-reverse-lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413143/drf-many-to-one-reverse-lookup)

Comment: + instead of using ForeignKey relationship in your model try use 
One-to-one relationship because you shouldn't have an object from ModelA with "is_main" set as true in an object and in another set as false

Comment: @seif model_b is photos object, it contains a main photo